# How to expand the space of the partition /dev/sdf4 until the end of the sdcard ? Neither resize2fs nor gparted work correctly

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, gpt

I would like to resize the /dev/sdf4 partition located on the sd card mounted on my Ubuntu 22.04 distro. I tried to accomplish this task using two approaches :

1. using the command resizefs,but it failed :

**mario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/media/ziomario/Elements/Backup/ChromeBook# resize2fs /dev/sdf4
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021). The filesystem is already 1174779 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!**

2. I've tried with gparted,but it also failed. This is what I did :

[image: 1] : **this is the partition that I want to extend...**

[image: 2] : **from 4589 to 180577...**

[image: 3] : **...as you can see it asks if I want to continue with the current settings. If I say "yes",it will not resize the partition. If I say "no",it will resize the partition and it will fix the error that you see,but when I insert the sd card inside the netbook,ubuntu installed on the sd card will not boot.**

This is the log messages that I see on the Terminal :

```
mario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/media/ziomario/Elements/Backup/ChromeBook# gparted /dev/sdf
GParted 1.3.1
configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
libparted 3.4
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 

** (gpartedbin:44337): WARNING **: 20:16:57.049: invalid substitution "%s" in fmt string "percorso: %1 (%s)"
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
```

Comment: The resize filesystem operation changes the UUID, so the old grub boot information, using the old UUID wont work anymore.  You could edit in the new UUID (find it with sudo blkid) or run an update-grub from an install media.

Comment: sorry for the typo. I'm not running 21.04,but 22.04 : fixed.